# Infinite loop trying to stop

Tags: loops, infinite

this should not be too terribly hard but i am still new to java so i would like some help with this function. i am using the code from my programming book. i copied and pasted the code in and i keep getting an infinite loop on the first message. i cannot figure out where the issue is that is causing this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BradySkuza44
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n;
        String message;

        System.out.println( "Type in a message, and I'll display it five times." );
        System.out.print( "Message: " );
        message = keyboard.nextLine();

        for ( n = 1 ; n <= 5 ; n++ )
        {
            System.out.println( n + ". " + message );
        }


        System.out.println( "\nNow I'll display it ten times and count by 5s.");
        for ( n = 5 ; n <= 50 ; n += 5 )
        {
            System.out.println( n + ". " + message );
        }

        System.out.println( "\nFinally, three times counting backward." );
        for ( n = 3 ; n > 0 ; n = 1 )
        {
            System.out.println( n + ". " + message );
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: `for ( n = 3 ; n > 0 ; n = 1 )` You always set n to 1.

Comment: replace  `for ( n = 3 ; n > 0 ; n = 1 )` with  `for ( n = 3 ; n > 0 ; n-- )`

Comment: for ( n = 3 ; n > 0 ; n-=1 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a newbie i'd rather use those for loops in a more conventional matter, using a different instance of int type `n` in every loop, this way only one instance of `n` will exist in each of the `for` blocks, which is actually the right scope for `n`

```
String message;

System.out.println( "Type in a message, and I'll display it five times." );
System.out.print( "Message: " );
message = keyboard.nextLine();

for (int n = 1 ; n <= 5 ; n++ )
{
    System.out.println( n + ". " + message );
}


System.out.println( "\nNow I'll display it ten times and count by 5s.");
for (int n = 5 ; n <= 50 ; n += 5 )
{
    System.out.println( n + ". " + message );
}

System.out.println( "\nFinally, three times counting backward." );
for (int n = 3 ; n > 0 ; n -- )
{
    System.out.println( n + ". " + message );
}
```

but your mistake is actually that you forgot to add a `-` in the last one, it should be `n-=1` or `n--` instead of `n=1` remember that `=` is always assignation

Comment: you are correct in attributing the instantiation of integer to the `for` block, but where you say "this way only one instance of `n` will exist", is misleading as there is not a second instance created, the same instance is reused across all 3 `for` statements.

Comment: thanks, i updated my answer to be a little more specific. This kind of mistakes actually misleads the rookies, being one my self.